# Sony Camera Remote API delete

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I'm developing app thats control Sony camera over the wifi. In "PlayMemories" Android app there is format option under the settings menu, that erases all the images on the cameras SD card, but in the camera API documentation I cannot see this method.

To delete the content I'm using following methods with parameters:

1. getContentCount - version = 1.2, target = all = flat, cnt = 100, stIdx = x
2. getContentList - version = 1.3, view = flat, cnt = 100, stIdx = x
3. deleteContent - version = 1.1

, but when I delete content ( 100 images in one request), camera led blinks with color red and turns off-on and I'm loosing Request connection, but with PlayMemory App I cannot see this behaviour.

Is there known reason why camera turns off-on, when deleting images?
Is there method that formats or delete  images and movies directories?

Comment: I found method "actFormatStorage", but i do not know all params, i know:

version = 1.0

service = camera

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, actFormatStorage is not a public API so you won't be able to access it.  Are you getting any kind of response from the calls you are making?  What happens if you try to delete less than 100 items?